# Loading component defined in one qml to another qml

Tags: qt, qml

I have created a Component as shown below.
My question is: Using loader i am loading textComponent in one qml. Can i load textComponent in any other qml files too ?? If yes then how to load Component of this type?

```
    Item {
    id: window
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height * 0.21

    property Component textComponent: Item {
        id: txtComp
        width: window.width * 0.80
        height: window.height * 0.16

        RowLayout {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            spacing: 10
            Text {
                text: defaultText
                color: "white"
            }
        }

 Rectangle {
        id: background
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        color: "black"

        Loader {
            id: textComponentLoader
            width: textComponent.width
            height: textComponent.height
            sourceComponent: textComponent
        }
    }
```

Note: Using inline components i am getting error as shown in the screenshot:

[image]
[image]

Comment: `textComponent` is the property name, not a type. Define custom type in a separate qml file and load it using `Loader.source`.  Please read [Defining Object Types](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-documents-definetypes.html) from the Qt docs.

Comment: When i using inline components i am getting error :     QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/main.qml:13:19: Unexpected token `identifier'

Comment: @folibis .... I have added the screenshot in the question asked above. Please let me know what mistake i am doing here?

Comment: what is `component`? Did you follow some tutorial or whatever? Please read the doc from the link I've provided.

Comment: @folibis... The above code(i.e. component) i have copy pasted from the link you shared. Used the syntax from the link you shared : component <component name> : BaseType {
    // declare properties and bindings here
}

Comment: What version of Qt are you using? Inline components are a new feature of Qt 5.15

Answer (score 1):

Ok, to avoid excessive comments, I'll just provide some code example for your question.

suppose you have some custom component:

CustomComponent.qml

```js
import QtQuick 2.15

Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height:  100
    color: "orange"
}
```

now you can use it as is, for example:

```js
CustomComponent
{
    anchors.centerIn: parent
}
```

using `Loader`:

```js
Loader {
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    source: "CustomComponent.qml"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@folibis's answer is most likely what you want to do, but I wanted to point out that you can access Components as properties of other objects, just like you would any other property. You're already defining your component as a property, like this:

```
// SomeObject.qml
Item {
    property Component someComponent: Item {
        // 
    }
}
```

Now in your other object, if you have an instance of the first object, you can access its properties.

```
// SomeOtherObject.qml
Item {
    SomeObject {
        id: someObject
    }

    Loader {
        sourceComponent: someObject.someComponent
    }
}
```